# VMware Tools installation on CentOS 6.10 Failed: Blocking File System Error

Tags: centos, vmware-workstation

Hello to the Linux SE!

I'm facing an error on CentOS 6.10 (x86_64 arch) running on VMware Workstation. I searched the internet for this issue. Some relevant threads by users on other sites and forums were posted, but with no success.

I didn't expect this error as I had no installation errors while installing Linux.

It happened when the VMware Tools installation triggered `/etc/vmware-tools/services.sh start` to start it.

[image: VMware Tools error]

> Note that the `VMware Tools` ISO file was not corrupted.

I had expected something wrong to happen when I saw this one at the finalization of installation:

[image: VMware Tools installation error]

It occurred at this step.

I tried to reinstall it completely. But still, the problem persists.

Comment: The installer seems to just be complaining that it failed to start the services, just like it fails when you try to start them by hand.

Comment: This irritation occurring since first-time installation of it.

Comment: Have you already seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32509470/vmware-tools-fails-on-centos-6-7-minimal-with-initctl-job-failed-to-start ? Note especially that "Blocking file system" requires FUSE to work.

Comment: Oh my god, I've found a lot, but didn't get that rare link. Thanks!